# How do I make images shrink when the screen is reduced?

Tags: html, css, image, sass

I use flex boxes

html

```
<div class="sorts__descr">
    <p>bla bla</p>
    <div class="coffee">
       <img src="./img/sorts/rob.png" alt="coffee">
    </div>
</div>
```

sass

```
&__descr
        display: flex
        justify-content: space-between
        align-items: start
        img
            position: relative
            margin: 0 40px
            max-width: 530px
            border-radius: 20px
        p
            font-size: 18px
            line-height: 135%
```

The output is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4b26.png)

I tried using different methods such as:

```
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

or

```
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
```

or

```
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
```

When I specify max-width: 100% for an image, the result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWclt.png)

I want it to be like this when the screen is zoomed out:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7sNk.png)

Comment: Hi, what do you want it to look like, equal width for both img and text?

Comment: @AHaworth I want the maximum width of the image to be 530px. And when the screen was reduced, img was proportionally reduced

Comment: have you try `width:100%; max-width:530px; height:auto ` ?

Comment: So your first image is what you want, not half and half?

Comment: @Sfili_81 Yes and here's what came out of it: [link](https://i.ibb.co/gFpxsZ8/image.png)

Comment: @AHaworth I want that when the screen is reduced, the structure does not break, and it was like this: [link](https://i.ibb.co/cy7Qx5g/image.png)

Comment: Is that half and half? Sorry to persist, but if you let the img go up as high as 530px it is going to shrink the text a lot, I don't think that is what you want. Do you want the text and image to be equal widths up until the img is 530px, and then the text to have all the rest?

Comment: You should post your whole HTML code and associated CSS of that screenshot, so we can see what you've done and advise you from what you have. there is many ways to do what you want, with and without flex.

Comment: @AHaworth Nothing wrong.I want the image to have a width of 530px. But when the screen is reduced, so that the text presses on the image and it decreases. But now it turns out the opposite, that the image presses on the text and the text moves to a new line

Comment: So is there to be a minimum width for the text - not sure what 'presses on' means.

Comment: @AHaworth I specified the minimum width for the text. Excellent, text is not reduced. But I need to shrink the image [link](https://i.ibb.co/zGJ3ZLG/image.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to make the website [responsive](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Image</h2>
<p>When the CSS width property is set in a percentage value, the image will scale up and down when resizing the browser window. Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>

<img src="img_girl.jpg" style="width:100%;">

</body>
</html>
```